# Get specific columns from xml path

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, for-xml-path

I have this query here:

```
SELECT      
    T.AKSIONERET, 
    sd.Identification_No, sd.Date_Of_Incorp, 
    sd.Ownership_Desc, sd.Ownership_Code, 
    sd.Subject_Name_Code, sd.Subject_Name, 
    sd.Subject_Type_Code, 
    LEFT(sd.Object_Desc, 3999) AS Object_Desc, 
    sd.Subject_Status_Name, sd.Subject_Name, 
    nr2.NACE_Code, nr2.NACE_PARENT, nr2.Description, 
    sd.Subject_Type_Name, sd.Subject_Status_Name, 
    sd.Subject_Type_Name, f.Place_Of_Registration, sd.Object_Desc
FROM            
    NRC_Subject_DEF AS sd 
LEFT JOIN 
    NRC_Nace_REV2 AS nr2 ON nr2.Subject_DEF_Code = sd.Subject_DEF_Code 
LEFT JOIN 
    NRC_ForeignCompany AS f ON sd.ForeignCompany_Code = f.ForeignCompany_Code             
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         SDP.Subject_DEF_Code,
         (SELECT 
              SDP1.Subject_DEF_Code, P.First_Name + ' ' + P.Last_Name + '-' + P.Citizenship_Desc AS FullAksionerCitizenship
          FROM 
              NRC_PeopleAddress P 
          INNER JOIN 
              NRC_SubjectDefPeople SDP1 ON SDP1.People_Code = P.People_Code
          WHERE 
              SDP1.Subject_DEF_Code = SDP.Subject_DEF_Code                         
          GROUP BY 
              SDP1.Subject_DEF_Code,  P.First_Name + ' ' + P.Last_Name + '-' + P.Citizenship_Desc 
          FOR XML PATH('')) AS AKSIONERET
      FROM 
          NRC_SubjectDefPeople SDP 
      WHERE 
          SDP.Groyp_Type IN (1,2)           
      GROUP BY 
          SDP.Subject_DEF_Code) AS T ON T.Subject_DEF_Code = SD.SUBJECT_DEF_CODE
```

I need to retrieve, instead of `T.AKSIONERET` the `FullAksionerCitizenship` which I get from the for xml path.

I know I have to do some other `SELECT` but I kept getting errors, syntax errors.

Could someone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could copy the last LEFT JOIN which includes this column. Then you take away all the other information. Thus you will get this column once within your XML construct and again as stand alone column

Comment: @Shnugo could you please paste the code how should i do this?

Comment: Did so... Please vote up / mark as helpful (if helpful :-)  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite sure, that there could be a better design and I'm not able to run this against test data off course, but this could work:

```
SELECT      
    T.AKSIONERET, 
    T2.FullAksionerCitizenship,
    sd.Identification_No, sd.Date_Of_Incorp, 
    sd.Ownership_Desc, sd.Ownership_Code, 
    sd.Subject_Name_Code, sd.Subject_Name, 
    sd.Subject_Type_Code, 
    LEFT(sd.Object_Desc, 3999) AS Object_Desc, 
    sd.Subject_Status_Name, sd.Subject_Name, 
    nr2.NACE_Code, nr2.NACE_PARENT, nr2.Description, 
    sd.Subject_Type_Name, sd.Subject_Status_Name, 
    sd.Subject_Type_Name, f.Place_Of_Registration, sd.Object_Desc
FROM            
    NRC_Subject_DEF AS sd 
LEFT JOIN 
    NRC_Nace_REV2 AS nr2 ON nr2.Subject_DEF_Code = sd.Subject_DEF_Code 
LEFT JOIN 
    NRC_ForeignCompany AS f ON sd.ForeignCompany_Code = f.ForeignCompany_Code             
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         SDP.Subject_DEF_Code,
         (SELECT 
              SDP1.Subject_DEF_Code, P.First_Name + ' ' + P.Last_Name + '-' + P.Citizenship_Desc AS FullAksionerCitizenship
          FROM 
              NRC_PeopleAddress P 
          INNER JOIN 
              NRC_SubjectDefPeople SDP1 ON SDP1.People_Code = P.People_Code
          WHERE 
              SDP1.Subject_DEF_Code = SDP.Subject_DEF_Code                         
          GROUP BY 
              SDP1.Subject_DEF_Code,  P.First_Name + ' ' + P.Last_Name + '-' + P.Citizenship_Desc 
          FOR XML PATH('')) AS AKSIONERET
      FROM 
          NRC_SubjectDefPeople SDP 
      WHERE 
          SDP.Groyp_Type IN (1,2)           
      GROUP BY 
          SDP.Subject_DEF_Code) AS T ON T.Subject_DEF_Code = SD.SUBJECT_DEF_CODE
--here starts the new block (difficult for me without knowing your db...)
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         (SELECT 
              SDP1.Subject_DEF_Code, P.First_Name + ' ' + P.Last_Name + '-' + P.Citizenship_Desc AS FullAksionerCitizenship
          FROM 
              NRC_PeopleAddress P 
          INNER JOIN 
              NRC_SubjectDefPeople SDP1 ON SDP1.People_Code = P.People_Code
          WHERE 
              SDP1.Subject_DEF_Code = SDP.Subject_DEF_Code                         
          GROUP BY 
              SDP1.Subject_DEF_Code,  P.First_Name + ' ' + P.Last_Name + '-' + P.Citizenship_Desc 
          ) AS FullAksionerCitizenship
      FROM 
          NRC_SubjectDefPeople SDP 
      WHERE 
          SDP.Groyp_Type IN (1,2)           
      GROUP BY 
          SDP.Subject_DEF_Code) AS T2 ON T2.Subject_DEF_Code = SD.SUBJECT_DEF_CODE
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot a comma after T2.FullAksionerCitizenship